# Update replace a part of the string in one column with part of a string from another column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Please help me with this query.
I am trying to replace a part of the string in one column with part of a string from another column
the table should look like

```
image_url                                 |          video_url
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://siteurl/folder/folder/folder/     |          https://siteurl/folder/folder/folder/
folder/folder/folder/xyz.jpg              |           folder/folder/folder/folder/xyz.mp4
```

I am trying to update the folder path of the video_url with the one from the image url .The folders manes are all completely different on different rows
I have tried the below but this throws an error

```
UPDATE `tbl` 
set video_url = REPLACE(video_url,
                        SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(video_url, "/", 10), 
                        SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_url, "/", 9)) 
where image_url like '%ch1%'
```

I anyone can provide a solution it would be great help

Comment: Your question is unclear; especially when there is no expected output. Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I think it should work if you remove the two `SELECT` (nevermind, the "find" part of `REPLACE` can be present multiple times)

Comment: @Pepper . I removed the SELECT in the REPLACE. But the file name was erased too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you want but try this:

```
UPDATE Table
SET video_url = 
CONCAT(
   LEFT(image_url, LENGTH(image_url) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(image_url))), 
   '/', 
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(video_url, '/', -1)
);
```

This will replace the folders path on video_url column with the folders path from image_url column.